# How does Russia deal with illegal Chinese immigrants?

Tags: russian-federation, china

> Aside from resident contract workers, 1.1 million Chinese also went to
> the border areas of the Russian Far East on tourist visas from 1997 to
> 2002.[28] Despite the perception that many remain illegally in Russia, since 1996, over 97% of Chinese arriving on tourist visas departed on
> time by the same border crossing through which they entered Russia,
> and many of the remaining 3% either departed by other border
> crossings, or were arrested and deported.[32][34]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_Chinese_in_Russia

Given that there's a large undercount of the Chinese population in Russia, I was wondering if the Russian government is lax in arresting and deporting illegal Chinese immigrants living in Russia. I am also wondering if the uneven relationship that Russia has with China might force them to be more lenient towards the Chinese.